# Swift 3. Hiding an empty tableView using Core Data

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3

I have tried to hide my `tableView` when it's empty using following line of code inside of the `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad` methods:

```
let count = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count == 0
    self.tableView.isHidden = count
```

But it's doesn't work. 
How to hide a `tableView` when it's empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to hide the table when it's empty?
I would rather provide one big table row with information like 'No results found' or something.

But if you need to display other UI stuff when no results:

Try to use the function with fetchRequest.

```
let count = managedContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) == 0
```

Comment: Yeah! You're right. I want to show another UI elements when the `tableView` is empty and as well as hidden. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's what I've done with your help! `let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Subclass> = Subclass.fetchRequest()
            do {
                let count = try self.managedObjectContext.count(for: fetchRequest) == 0
                self.tableView.isHidden = count
            } catch {}
`